# jQuery click for rendering page yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I have column of gridview. this is the following the code :

```
 [
     'format' => 'raw',
     'value' => function ($model) {
            return "<p class='feedback'>" . $model->KOMENTAR . "</p><br><p class='feedback-date'>" . $model->TANGGAL . "</p><hr><div id='replay-" . $model->ID_KOMENTAR . "'><ul></ul><div id='replay-column'></div></div>";
     },
 ]
```

this is the jQuery I write :

```
$("#replay-to-"+ID_KOMENTAR).on("click", function(){
    //and this is the wrong code
    //$.get('index.php?r=feedback/feedbacktest',null, function(data){
    //  $('#replay-column').append(data);
    //});
});
```

I want to render page when the button click, I was trying some code but it just got error

```
<?= $this->render('feedback_form', [
   'model' => $model,
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following simple `$.ajax`

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "index.php?r=feedback/feedbacktest",
    method: "GET""
});
request.done(function( data) {
    $('#replay-column').append(data);
});
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Just make sure that your `url` is correct one and see whether you get any error or not.